# Ubuntu 22.04 cannot resume from suspend after the lid is opened

Tags: suspend, asus, 22.04, hibernate

I am using Ubuntu 22.04 and it should hibernate after the lid is closed and should resume when it is opened. But it cannot resume after the lid is opened and it restarts.

I have noticed that a few questions similar to mine got the answer that `Your hardware cannot support the suspension of Ubuntu`. But this problem did not exist after the installation of Ubuntu 22.04 and it emerged a few days after the installation.

I have also noticed that when my laptop is plugged the whole time of its suspension, then it **can** resume from it. But if it is not plugged, it cannot resume and it will reboot itself. This does not happen because of the drained battery: sometimes after the reboot, the laptop has more than 80% charge.

What's causing the problem? I remember after installing a plethora of applications, my laptop froze and I had to force restart it and the problem began. I am using ASUS V502U.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed it. I thought to myself that there is no use closing the lid without shutting my laptop off, since it is not going to resume anyway.

So the last time, first I powered my laptop off, and then closed the lid. Then when I started my laptop, the problem was solved and it could resume after after the lid was closed!

I don't know what was the problem, but after that the problem happened again when the battery died when I was working with my laptop (the battery is old and this happens sometimes when not plugged in.) But the same steps fixed it again. Maybe it will work for you too.